# Topological proof that a continuous injective real function on an interval has a continuous inverse

Tags: general-topology, continuity

The text *Topology and Groupoids* by Brown states the following on page 8 in Chapter 1:

> 1.2.4 (Inverse rule.) Let $f \colon A \to \mathbb{R}$ be a real function which is injective, so that $f$ has an inverse $f^{-1} \colon f[A] \to A$. If $A$ is an interval and $f$ is continuous, then $f^{-1}$ is continuous.
>
> For a proof see many books on a first course in analysis. This result
> is also a consequence of general theorems on connectivity and compactness [cf. Chapter 3]. The assumption that $A$ is an interval is essential [cf.
> Exercise 4 of Section 1.2].

Chapter 1 of this book is mostly about preparing the reader for a study of topological spaces in general beginning in Chapter 2. In that spirit, I am wondering if there is a topological proof of 1.2.4, i.e. one using neighborhoods.

I have checked the following books:

1. Analysis I, by Tao
2. Elementary Analysis, by Ross
3. Real Analysis and Foundations, by Krantz
4. Real Mathematical Analysis, by Pugh
5. Understanding Analysis, by Abbott
6. Introduction to Analysis, by Bartle and Sherbert
7. Principles of Mathematical Analysis, by Rudin
8. Analysis I, by Amann and Escher
9. Real Analysis, by Carothers

and I didn't see any neighborhood-style proofs of a result like 1.2.4. (Maybe I missed it?) I've also searched StackExchange but haven't found what I'm looking for.

**Questions:**

Does anyone know of a proof of result 1.2.4 using neighborhoods? Should I just wait until result 1.2.4 falls out as a special case of more general theorems later in the book?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The intermediate value theorem is all that you need to show that $f$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing, and that $f[A]$ is order-convex, meaning that whenever $x<y<z$, and $x,z\in f[A]$, then $y\in f[A]$. This means that $f[A]$ must be all of $\Bbb R$, a ray, or an interval, i.e., that it must have one of the following forms: $\Bbb R$; $(\leftarrow,a)$, $(\leftarrow,a]$, $(a,\to)$, or $[a,\to)$ for some $a\in\Bbb R$; or $(a,b)$, $[a,b)$, $(a,b]$, or $[a,b]$ for some $a,b\in\Bbb R$. The intermediate value theorem is also all that you need to show that if $[a,b]\subseteq A$, then

$$f\big[[a,b]\big]=\begin{cases}
[f(a),f(b)],&\text{if }f\text{ is increasing}\\
[f(b),f(a)],&\text{if }f\text{ is decreasing.}
\end{cases}$$

Now suppose that $(a,b)\subseteq A$. Note that $a$ and $b$ need not belong to $A$. However,

$$(a,b)=\bigcup_{a<c<d<b}[c,d]\;,$$

so

$$\begin{align*}
f[(a,b)]&=\bigcup_{a<c<d<b}f\big[[c,d]\big]\\
&=\begin{cases}
\left(\inf_\limits{a<c<b}f(c),\sup_\limits{a<c<b}f(d)\right),\text{ if }f\text{ is increasing}\\
\left(\inf_\limits{a<c<b}f(c),\sup_\limits{a<c<b}f(c)\right),\text{ if }f\text{ is decreasing}\;.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

(It’s possible that $\inf_\limits{a<c<b}f(c)=-\infty$ or $\sup_\limits{a<c<b}f(c)=+\infty$; in that case $f\big[(a,b)\big]$ is $\Bbb R$ or an open ray.)

If $a=\min A$, a basic open nbhd of $a$ has the form $[a,b)$ for some $a<b\in A$, and

$$f\big[[a,b)\big]=\begin{cases}
\big[f(a),f(b)\big),&\text{if }f\text{ is increasing}\\
\big(f(b),f(a)\big],&\text{if }f\text{ is decreasing.}
\end{cases}$$

A corresponding result holds for intervals of the form $(a,b]$ if $b=\max A$, so $f$ is open as well as bijective, and the inverse of an open bijection is continuous.

Comment: I will need some time to understand what you've written. I guess the result I asked about is really just a real analysis result, not a topology result. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Novice: You’re welcome. Using a little topology makes it easier without changing the argument much. For instance, you can use directly the fact that continuous functions map connected sets to connected sets, instead of going by way of the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following theorem from topology:

If $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous bijection of topological spaces where $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff then $f$ is a homeomorphism (has continuous inverse).

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Bijection_from_Compact_to_Hausdorff_is_Homeomorphism

Comment: What if OP’s interval $A$ isn’t closed and bounded?  Is there a way to salvage it?

Comment: I'm also interested to hear whether whether this proof can be salvaged for non-compact intervals.

Comment: @Novice: It can, if you’re familiar with the [extended reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line). Let $a=\inf A$ and $b=\sup A$, and show that there is a continuous $g:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ such that $g\upharpoonright A=f$. Noel Lundström’s argument now applies to $g$, and $g^{-1}\upharpoonright f[A]=f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

If the function $f$ is injective, and continuous then it is monotone, by the intermediate value theorem.  Then you need only note that the open sets on both $A$ and $f(A)$ are induced by their orderings.  Note that $f(A)$ is also an interval, again by the intermediate value theorem.

Note this works for open intervals $A$ as well as compact ones.

Snake eating its tail (mentioned in comments).  Red arcs indicate where open ends of interval go.

[image: Snake eating its tail]

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but this seems like more of a real analysis style proof.

Comment: @Novice Not sure if what you want is possible.  If your continuous function was from an interval to $\mathbb{R}^2$, then it could be injective without its inverse (on its image) being continuous (e.g. snake eating its tail).  Thus any proof will have to use properties of $\mathbb{R}$ which are not shared by $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Maybe you're right. I have to think more about this. I was under the impression that there would be a topological type of proof, but perhaps there isn't. Maybe it's basically just a real analysis result.